# How to promisify my Class in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I am using bluebird to implementing promisify in my custom lib. I have follwing lib
user, lib-1, lib-2 etc

On user registration, from my user router

```
// user_router.js
var user = new User();
var lib1 = new Lib1();
var lib2 = new Lib2();
// I am expecting, all method will be async by following 3 lines!
Promise.promisifyAll(user);
Promise.promisifyAll(lib1);
Promise.promisifyAll(lib2);
user.validationAsync(payload)
    .then(function(result_from_validation) {
              return lib1.validationAsync(payload);
          })
    .then(function(result_lib1_validation)) {
             return lib2.validationAsync(payload)
          })
    .then(function(result_lib2_validation)) {
             // final save 
             user.registerAsync(payload);
             lib1.saveAsync(payload);
             lib2.saveAsync(payload);
            return {'response-data'}
          })
    .then(function(response)) {
             // send response  
             res.json('success', 'User successfully created', {});
          })
    .catch(function(error)) {
             //all error will be handled here
             //these error will be either throw or by promise rejected.
             res.json('error', error.message, {error.stack});
          })
```

In validation method I am throwing errors like

```
//user_lib.js
// This throw will be handled by router catch. ???
throw Error('Field value is invalid');
```

In save method mongooes modal also have some validation like user already exist so unable to create user.

```
function register (payload)
{
  // payload data binded on user_modal here
  var user_modal = getUserModal(payload);
  user_modal.saveAsync()
            .then(function(){})
            .catch(function(error){
               //How to handle error here and send this error to router
             })
}
```

All above is just my expectation. I want to send all response from user_router.js. (***My user module already implemented***. now need to integrate it by bluebird)

**Now Question ::**

- How can I do it by bluebird ? How to set resolve/reject method on
  user object(explicitly) ??
- If validation method throw error then it
  will be captured by router catch method ???
- How can I send any
  error/rejection to router's catch from mongooes (see user register
  method)?

  I hope you will get my points. Thanks in advance!!
  You can also share any example link to implement these things.

Comment: Is your validation method itself async - does it take a callback where it returns the result? If so, it shouldn't throw, it should invoke the callback with the exception object as the first parameter. If not, I don't think promisify will actually do anything since it's not an async method, but I'll have to check the docs.

Comment: @ChrisTavares Thanks for your response. Validation method is not async.  So you recommend  me to use callback instead of throw any exception ??

Comment: Why are you trying to use promises if your methods are not async?  Just put an exception handler around your function call to catch any exception it throws.

Comment: @jfriend00 : Now I am doing your way! :)  But I expecting above structure in  my application architecture  so I can centralize all stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am using try catch for normal statement and using promise for async error handling!! :) Thanks a lot guyz